# Add a class along with class specified in the skin

Tags: asp.net, css, themes, skin

We are using themes to style our control.

For textbox we have added like this in the skin

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="txt edit_txt" />
```

Now in some cases, we want to add another class along with this 2 classes.

when we added a textbox like this in aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtnameE" runat="server" MaxLength="30" CssClass="RequiredCheckClass"></asp:TextBox>
```

On rendering it didn't take the "RequiredCheckClass" class, but only the other 2 classes specified in the skin.

So is there any way to add a class along with the classes specified in the skin from an aspx page.

PS : now i am going to use @Curt suggestion or will use EnableTheming=false and will add all the required classes to this control. Please update if anyone got any other idea other than these....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create another TextBox control in the Skin file like:

```
<asp:TextBox SkinID="Required" runat="server" CssClass="txt edit_txt RequiredCheckClass" />
```

And then use the following in your markup file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtnameE" runat="server" MaxLength="30" SkinID="Required"></asp:TextBox>
```

Other than that I'm not sure. I've always avoided ASP.NET Themes since I found out how restrictive they are.

Comment: yes.. but the issue is like we got a number of styles in the skin, and adding new skin object is like we have to do changes in  a lot of pages.. thats why we are looking for some other techinques..

Comment: @mahesh: I am in same situation. Have you found any solution for this rather than mentioned in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "class" property - just like you use it in a regular HTML element.
thats the bypass that i am using.

```
<asp:TextBox SkinID="Required" runat="server" class="RequiredCheckClass" CssClass="txt edit_txt" />
```